# jQuery table input in rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my app i have a form with 4 fields that records information about a friend. (see screenshot)

At the bottom i have a button that dynamically duplicates the form should the user want to enter another record.

They way i have it setup is sort of messy and will be extremely long should the user want to add lots of records.

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Maybe some sort of jquery table?

[image]

View code:

```
<div id="single_module">
<div class="pitch">
<h2>Step 3: Friends Birthdays</h2>
</div>
<form id="myForm">
<div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
<%= simple_form_for @user, url: wizard_path do |f| %>

  <div class="inputs">
  <ul class="testss1">
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :friends do |friend_f| %>
    <li>
    <%= friend_f.input :name %>
    </li>
    <li>
    <%= friend_f.input :dob, :as => :date_picker, :label => 'Birthday', :input_html => { :class => 'special' } %>
    <li>
    <%= friend_f.input :gender, :collection => ['male','female'] %></li>
    </li><li>
    <%= friend_f.association :interests, :as => :select, :label => false %></li>


    <%end%>

    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add another name" />
    <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="remove name" />
    </div>
    </form>
    <div class="actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, 'Next Step', :class => 'btn btn-primary',  %>
    <br></br>
    </div>
    <%end%>
```

Answer (score 2):

do you save each time when is done, add another friend click? why not to save you data even in   temporary hidden field, then clear all data in your form and let user add another record?

Comment: No it does not save to the database until the final is submitted.. how would that work with the hidden fields is say the user adds 20 people? Is there a plugin that can be used or hacked to get this done?

Comment: in this case you can just hide your table, duplicate a new table,and show the new one. Better even make 2 table at the beginning, hide the second one, then if user wants to add a new one duplicate the hidden one insert it at the end and hide it the last one and show the hidden one. That's way you don't have to clear your controls

Comment: do you know of any existing plugins or tutorials on how to do this?.. im just getting into jquery